# Material UI Drawer opens when clicked on a link

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I used this code, modified. https://codesandbox.io/s/6xdsb
Its from the official website.

My drawer is opened by default, so `const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)` open is true,

I have the exact configuration except the links.

My problem is that when i close the drawer and i click on any link inside my drawer ( to navigate to other page), the drawer will open itself.

Best regards.

Comment: I saw it works.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help unless you share some of the code that is not working.  To me it sounds like an onClick={handleDrawerOpen} property was applied to the <Drawer> component, but I'm guessing without any more detailed info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.